# What web apps exist that have been designed for the iPad?

Tags: webapp-rec, ipad

I am interested in seeing any **web apps that have been designed for the iPad**, and from your experience - how well do they work on the device?

If they have **specifically added support for the iPad** on a popular web app at a later date, then this would count as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://everytimezone.com/ was designed for the iPad and also works offline if added to the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

Google designed an iPad-specific site. From the [Official Gmail Blog](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/04/gmail-on-ipad.html):

> When the iPhone and Android devices came out, we started building for advanced mobile browsers and optimizing the Gmail interface for touchscreens, culminating in the [Gmail for mobile](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/04/new-mobile-gmail-experience-for-iphone.html) HTML5 web app. As portable devices continue to evolve, we're excited about the upcoming wave of tablet computers and the possibilities they bring.
>
> With today's release of the iPad, we're launching an experimental two-pane user interface to take advantage of its large touchscreen and tablet form factor. Building upon the Gmail for mobile web app, this new interface displays your conversations on the left and your messages on the right hand side.
>
> All the features of the Gmail web app that you're used to, such as offline access and aggressive caching to reduce latency, are present in the iPad version. Tablet devices are still very new, so expect changes as we continue to optimize for this new format. We'd like to hear any ideas you may have on how we can make Gmail better for the iPad so don't hesitate to let us know via the 'Send feedback' link at the bottom of your inbox on iPad.
>
> To try out Gmail out on the iPad, just go to gmail.com in Safari. For quick access, try creating a homescreen link. Please note that the new interface is only available in US English for now. You can always access Gmail through the native Mail application using IMAP as well.

[image]
<sub>(source: [blogspot.com](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/_JE4qNpFW6Yk/S7ZT-me6BkI/AAAAAAAAAi4/I6xotE8C7NA/s1600/gmail_on_ipad.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

[Netvibes](http://netvibes.com) has an iPad specific version of their web application or "web dashboard" and they are looking to get users to try it out. You can read the details (and potentially sign up) [here](http://blog.netvibes.com/test-netvibes-on-ipad/). The nice thing is that there is no special code needed, you just can log in with your existing account to the special version [here](http://ipad.netvibes.com).

I've been a long time Netvibes user and would love to see how this works, but sadly I don't have the money to get an iPad. Netvibes has had a good reputation and app for a while now, so I'm guessing their putting good resources into it.

Answer (score 0):

[Threadsy](http://threadsy.com) has plans on building an iPad version of their app. You can see a confirmation of their intents through a couple of support posts ([here](http://getsatisfaction.com/threadsy/topics/threadsy_ipad_instagib_killer_app) and [here](http://getsatisfaction.com/threadsy/topics/i_cant_scroll_on_my_tablet_ipad_please_add_touch_support)). They want to finish and iPhone version of the application first. I do know that at one point in time they were looking to hire an iPad developer as well.

Answer (score 0):

CBS.com is [going to have an iPad-ready site](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/cbs_publicly_testing_ipad-ready_video.php) which will allow you to stream video content.

Answer (score 0):

One of the coolest web apps for iPad is a game!

http://touchsolitaire.mobi/

If you "add to home screen" from Safari you can play offline because it's an HTML5 app and it makes use of offline storage.